# Visual studio - how to include correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, path, include

The question is about existing project which is compiled and executed successfully - I try to add to it some functionality

In the project in path  `C:\TestProject\components\VolumeUtilities\Include\Ilistener.h`
I have following code :

```
#include <vector>
#include "VolumeUtilitiesDefs.h"
#include "..\Map3D\IProvider.h"
#include "PolygonsAlgorithms.h"



namespace volumeutilities
{
    class IListener
    {
       //code
    };
}
```

I want anther (existing) class to inherit from `IListener`.
This class is path is `C:\TestProject\components\Sound\SoundManager\SoundManager.h`
And in properties ->general -> additonal include ../..
So I added

```
#include "VolumeUtilities/Include/IListener.h"
```

looks that this part is ok, but in `Ilistener.h` new problem appeared - it can`t include

```
#include "..\Map3D\IProvider.h" (no such path or directory)
```

I think that compiler searches for IProvider.h in C:\TestProject\components\Sound\Map3D
instead of C:\TestProject\components\VolumeUtilities\Include
How the issue could be solved?

Comment: You need to set up your header search paths correctly and make your includes relative to the *search path*, instead of the file.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, `IProvider.h` and `IListener.h` are in the same folder `C:\TestProject\components\VolumeUtilities\Include`. If so, you could add `C:\TestProject\components\VolumeUtilities\Include` rather than `#include "VolumeUtilities/Include/IListener.h"` in  `properties ->general -> Additonal Include Directories`. I suggest that you could click the button.

[image]